# React add document firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I have a problem on code below I can't add a firestore collection to a db, when the setDoc line is executed it doesn't add the document to the collection, and the strange thing is that it doesn't print anything console, I'm using react, even though I use the add doc it does the same thing, the app is already connected to firebase because I logged in so the parameters are correct, what can it be?

**FirebaseFile.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

var firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
var app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

**Another.js**

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { doc, setDoc,collection } from 'firebase/firestore';

import styled from 'styled-components';
import EmailEditor from '../../../src';
import sample from './sample.json';
import sample2 from './sample2.json';
import sample3 from './sample3.json';
import { db } from '../firebase';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import axios from 'axios';
const label = { inputProps: { 'aria-label': 'Checkbox demo' } };

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
`;

const Bar = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 40px;

  h1 {
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;
  }

  button {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0px;
    max-width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;

const Example = () => {
  const emailEditorRef = useRef(null);
  const [titolo, setTitolo] = useState('');
  const [newsProfileValue, setNewsProfileSet] = useState('');
  const [profileList, setNewsProfileList] = useState([]);
  const [premiumValue, setPremium] = useState(false);
  const [publicValue, setPublic] = useState(false);
  const arr = [];

  const saveDesign = () => {
    emailEditorRef.current.editor.saveDesign((design) => {
      exportData(design);
    });
  };

  const getList = async () => {
    try {
      //Recupero lo user id
      var id = await localStorage.getItem('uid');
      console.log(id);
      var data = [];
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'news_profiles'));
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        if (doc.data().about.uid == id) {
          data.push({ title: doc.data().about.title, id: doc.id });
          arr.push({ doc: doc.data().about.title, id: doc.id });
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error: ' + error);
    }
    var options = arr.map((e) => {
      return `<option value="${e.id}">${e.doc}</option>`;
    });
    document.getElementById('selectNumber').innerHTML = options;
    setNewsProfileList(data);
  };

  const exportData = (design) => {
    const jsonString = `data:text/json;chatset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(
      JSON.stringify(design)
    )}`;
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = jsonString;
    link.download = 'data.json';
    link.click();
  };
  const exportHtml = () => {
    console.log('Sono in export html');
    addElementToFireStoreNews('prova');
    emailEditorRef.current.editor.exportHtml((data) => {
      const { design, html } = data;
      console.log('Sono dentor export');
      addElementToFireStoreNews(html);
      console.log("Sono dentor l'export");
    });
  };

  const addElementToFireStoreNewsAWS = async (html) => {
    var jsonFile;
    var templateid = await localStorage.getItem('templateid');
    if (templateid == 1) {
      jsonFile = sample;
    } else if (templateid == 2) {
      jsonFile = sample3;
    } else {
      jsonFile = sample2;
    }
    //Salvo la newsletter su aws
    emailEditorRef.current.editor.exportHtml((data) => {
      const { design, html } = data;
      var dataValue = {
        internal: true,
        online: publicValue,
        premium: premiumValue,
        html: html,
        template: jsonFile,
        subject: html,
        email: uuid,
      };
      axios
        .post(
          `https://europe-west3-mindit-newsletter.cloudfunctions.net/newsCreate`,
          dataValue
        )
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.json());
        });
    });
  };
  const addElementToFireStoreNews = async (html) => {
    console.log("Sono nell'inserimento del html");
    try {
      //addElementToFireStoreNewsAWS(html);
      var uuid = await localStorage.getItem('uid');
      const value = {
        aboutNews: {
          email: newsProfileValue,
          html: html,
          internal: true,
          photo: '',
          title: titolo,
        },
        date: new Date(),
        id: uuid,
        measures: {
          impression: {
            total: 0,
          },
          views: {
            moth: 0,
            total: 0,
            week: 0,
          },
        },
        public: true,
        searchKey: '',
        premium: premiumValue,
      };

      const newCityRef = doc(collection(db, 'news'));
      await setDoc(newCityRef, value);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Errore inserimnento: ' + err);
    }
  };

  const onDesignLoad = (data) => {
    console.log('onDesignLoad', data);
  };

  const onLoad = async () => {
    getList();

    var templateid = await localStorage.getItem('templateid');
    if (templateid == 1) {
      emailEditorRef.current.editor.loadDesign(sample);
    } else if (templateid == 2) {
      emailEditorRef.current.editor.loadDesign(sample3);
    } else {
      emailEditorRef.current.editor.loadDesign(sample2);
    }
    emailEditorRef.current.editor.addEventListener(
      'design:loaded',
      onDesignLoad
    );
  };

  const onReady = () => {};

  const changeText = (text) => {
    setTitolo(text);
  };

  const clickValue = (e) => {
    setNewsProfileSet(e.target.value);
  };

  const changeValue = () => {
    setPremium(!premium);
  };
  const changeValuePublic = () => {
    setPublic(!publicValue);
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Bar>
        <img src="firebase.png" width="100" height="50" />
        <label style={{ color: 'white' }}>
          <b>Titolo News: </b>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            onChange={(value) => changeText(value.target.value)}
            style={{ marginRight: 200 }}
          />
          Premium:{' '}
          <Checkbox
            {...label}
            unchecked
            onClick={() => changeValue()}
            style={{ color: 'white' }}
          />
          Online:{' '}
          <Checkbox
            {...label}
            unchecked
            onClick={() => changeValuePublic()}
            style={{ color: 'white' }}
          />
        </label>
        <form id="myForm">
          <select id="selectNumber" onClick={clickValue}>
            <option>Scegli il news profile</option>
          </select>
          <button onClick={() => saveDesign}> Salva Design </button>
          <button onClick={() => addElementToFireStoreNews('prova')}>
            {' '}
            Salva Articolo{' '}
          </button>{' '}
        </form>
      </Bar>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <EmailEditor ref={emailEditorRef} onLoad={onLoad} onReady={onReady} />{' '}
      </React.StrictMode>{' '}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you merged two files but you listed this as one file. If that's one file, then you are importing `db` twice which would be a problem:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

var firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
var app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app); <-------- Use this.

import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { doc, setDoc,collection } from 'firebase/firestore';

import styled from 'styled-components';
import EmailEditor from '../../../src';
import sample from './sample.json';
import sample2 from './sample2.json';
import sample3 from './sample3.json';
import { db } from '../firebase'; <----- What is this?
```

Otherwise, if you are having the problem locally, make sure you are starting your local `Firestore Emulator` or else you'll probably be updating your live Firestore instance.

```
// detect for development ENV
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, '127.0.0.1', 6060);
```

Comment: my error file is different